# TeXworks pdflatex compilation does not terminate

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texworks

I am new to LaTeX. I took a sample tex code and tried to typeset using TeXworks after choosing pdflatex option. I get this displayed in the console output.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9)
```

But apart from this, there is nothing and the compilation does not terminate - the red logo with white x is displayed no matter how long I wait. I have to click on that to manually terminate. No file is generated by compilation process in the folder. This is the code that I tried to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\title{Premier document}
\author{Un TeXnicien}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Even if there are errors in my code, I would expect error messages. This seems like I have started running an infinite loop. What should I do to generate pdf file? I have been spending hours on this with no solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried this compilation with command line, LEd and LyX. And the compilation does not terminate in any of these!

Comment: I failed to reproduce your error. It works perfectly in my computer. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So there's nothing wrong with the code. Have I missed something during configuration of MikTex?

Comment: Delete any related `.aux` file and try again. Also try from the commandline or another editor. Also consider looking at the `.log` file (one *should* be generated) to see if any errors are mentioned.

Comment: I tried from command line and from Led editor. Same problem. But sorry where do I look for the `.aux` file? It is not in the folder where I have my `.tex` file.

Comment: @jon Thanks but no `.log` file either.

Comment: You tried, and..?  When you type `pdflatex myfile.tex` or `latex myfile.tex` (where 'myfile.tex') is the name of your file, what happens? Does it only print that first line?

Comment: @jon Yes. Only "This is PdfTex..." is printed. Only that and the cursor blinks. I have to close the cmd window to terminate.

Comment: Well, it's no infinite loop, but that's a problem I can't help you with if (as it seems) you're using Windows.

Comment: Yes I am using Windows. But I wonder if this problem has anything to do with Windows. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does your file name contain spaces?

Comment: Nope. It's sample.tex

Comment: @Usha What happens if you try `pdflatex <filename>` at the Command Prompt?

Comment: @JosephWright Like I said before, I type `pdflatex sample2.tex` and I get `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9)` and the cursor blinks.

Comment: @Usha If that is all you are getting then something is wrong with your MiKTeX installation. It's relatively easy to end up with an infinite loop with TeX but I'd expect you to at least get the LaTeX banner and some file loading showing. I guess your best plan is to uninstall MiKTeX and then try installing again.

Comment: Try on the command line `initexmf --admin --force --mklinks`  (if you have only a single user installation leave out the `--admin`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. Thank you so much.. It worked. But could you please explain what it means. [Please post your comment as an answer].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your output looks as if the `pdflatex` executable is broken. It doesn't load the format. `pdflatex.exe` is only a small wrapper for a call to `pdftex` and can be remade with `initexmf` (http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/initexmf.html).

So try on the command line `initexmf --admin --force --mklinks` (if you have only a single user installation leave out the `--admin`).